# Radius of convergence of $\dfrac{z+1}{z-i}$ around $z_0 = 2+i$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm asked to find the radius of convergence of $\dfrac{z+1}{z-i}$ around $z_0 = 2+i$

The way I tried to go about it is by using the geometric series.

$$\dfrac{z+1}{z-i}= \dfrac{z}{z-i}+\dfrac{1}{z-i} = \dfrac{1}{\Big(1-\dfrac{i}{z}\Big)} + \dfrac{1}{z}.\dfrac{1}{\Big(1-\dfrac{i}{z}\Big)} = \displaystyle\sum\Big(\dfrac{i}{z}\Big)^k  + \dfrac{1}{z}∑\Big(\dfrac{i}{z}\Big)^k .$$
we can then use that the geometric series $\sum a^k$ converges to $\dfrac{1}{1-a}$ for $|a| < 1$ with $a = \dfrac{i}{z}$. So we say we must have $\Big|\dfrac{i}{z}\Big|<1$ i.e. $|z|>1$, making the radius of convergence $R = 1$.

Now, I know the answer is $R = 2$, so I know this is wrong, I just don't know why or where. And I also don't understand the relevance of $z_0 = 2 + i$ and where to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to expand with respect to $w:=z-z_0=z-2-i$:
$$\frac{z+1}{z-i}=\frac{w+3+i}{w+2}=
\frac{w/2}{1-(-w/2)}+\frac{(3+i)/2}{1-(-w/2)}.$$
Note that the geometric series involved is convergent when $|-w/2|<1$, that is $|z-z_0|<R=2$.

Comment: Thank you! I believe so. Do I need to do anything with the series after getting $\frac{w}{2}∑(\frac{-w}{2})^k + \frac{3+i}{2}∑(\frac{-w}{2})^k$ ? Or do I just leave it as is cuz I only need to find RoC and I did?

Comment: If you need just the radius, you are done.

Comment: If I shift the index how can I still sum them? are we not only allowed to sum terms with the same indexes? unless I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: Sorry, are you interested also  in the power series?

Comment: Not for this particular exercise, but for the chapter I'm working on in general so I'd like to know what you meant if you've the time.

Comment: We have that $$-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-w}{2})^k + \frac{3+i}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(\frac{-w}{2})^k.$$ Now take out the term for $k=0$ of the second sum and join the sums $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}$.

Comment: $\frac{3+i}{2}+\frac{1+i}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-w)^k$ ?

Comment: $\frac{3+i}{2}+\frac{1+i}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-w/2)^k$ (otherwise the radius becomes $1$!!).

Comment: right, my bad. I get it now though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem.** The radius of convergence of a power series development of an analytic function  $f$ at a point $a$ is the radius of the largest disc centred at $a$ and contained in the domain of $f.$

Here the domain of $f$ is $\mathbf{C}-\{i\}$ and the point $a = 2 + i,$ hence the largest disc has radius $|a-i|= 2.$ $\square$

Comment: Sorry, I guess we are employing  different definitions. A power series usually have a radius of convergence _larger_ than the radius of convergence of the power series _development_ of an analytic function. The latter is given as I stated.

Comment: That's fair enough.